# Silverlight an alternative to activeX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, activex

I have a question regarding hosting silverlight in asp.net web page. I have a functionality which I tried to achieve through activeX earlier but it didn't work out (hosting related issue etc) so now I am planning to get it done through silverlight.

But I have a doubt here, I want to know how will it work I mean where will silverlight code get executed (Client side or server side) if I call silverlight component's methods through java script ?

Can siliverlight be used as an alternative to activeX controls?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? That said, Silverlight run on the client side, but is mote of time relying on server side web services. Please keep in mind that SilverLigth is abandoned by Microsoft. IF possible, try to create a true Html/Javascript solution.

Comment: I have to run a report from a server but every time IE asks for username/pwd of the report server even though I have given user/pwd in the report url to connect to report server. This is not a case with FF/Chrome. I observed that if I add the report server url to the IE trusted sites list it works smoothly that's what I was trying to achieve through activeX. So all I want to achieve is to add the report server url to the trusted site list. I guess Silverlight should achieve this thing.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question related to your actual issue! And to be honest, there are plenty a way to show reports in a web page without any plugin (which is, I believe, a bad thing)

Comment: I had asked but no replies on that :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061533/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-with-activex-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

That is a lot of questions.

Silverlight will get executed on client side. You can call webservice though from silverlight which will then execute on server side. Silverlight is comparing to ActiveX "caged" - it is running in sandbox, which will get access only to limited set of functions and local resources (you can use them all, but then you'll have to ask user to run the app in trusted mode, which is not by default). Also it requires plugin in browser (while ActiveX at least for IE does not). You can invoke silverlight application methods trough javascript.

In summary - Silverlight can be alternative to ActiveX for some scenarios.

And as for ActiveX - I recommend do not use them at all, unless you absolutely have to.